# Force php to kill idle connection while stopping download from external remote point?

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, owncloud, nextcloud

I have nextcloud, and there is connected remote storage, it is fuse folder of rclone mounted as local */drive*.
On this */drive* I have some big files.

when I start to download some big file I see it in `bmon` that my vps is downloading it and serving to me.
But when I cancel it, it still is downloading until whole file is loaded somewhere into memory.

I have to do

```
service php7.0-fpm restart
```

to make it stop downloading.
I also tried

```
service nginx restart
```

but it does nothing.

Please help thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
php function: ignore_user_abort
https://github.com/nextcloud/server/pull/5328/files